# I want to convert from multiple column to rows in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like that

[image]

and i want result like the below table

[image]

i have tried (here i have column Region_Name in the same table)

```
select year, month,concat(Region_Name,'_SO'), sum(SO) from production_report  group by Year,Month,Team_Name union all
select year, month,concat(Region_Name,'_SP'), sum(SP) from production_report  group by Year,Month,Team_Name union all
select year, month,concat(Region_Name,'_DP'), sum(DP) from production_report  group by Year,Month,Team_Name union all
select year, month,concat(Region_Name,'_CS'), sum(CS) from production_report  group by Year,Month,Team_Name union all
select year, month,concat(Region_Name,'_TAB'), sum(TAB) from production_report  group by Year,Month,Team_Name union all
select year, month,concat(Region_Name,'_OE'), sum(OE) from  production_report  group by Year,Month,Team_Name;
```

but i am not getting the exact result.

Comment: Easy way: use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Write some SQL and show us. You have to make an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select year, month, team_name, SO from t where SO > 0 union all
select year, month, team_name, SP from t where SP > 0 union all
select year, month, team_name, DP from t where DP > 0 union all
select year, month, team_name, CS from t where CS > 0 union all
select year, month, team_name, TAB from t where TAB > 0 union all
select year, month, team_name, OE from t where OE > 0;
```

Comment: thanks for comment... i have already tried with union all but there is some error in where condition in my query and i correct it.